# Main .container - how to select - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I Have:

```
<header>
<div class="container"></container>
</header>

<div class="container"></div>

<footer>
<div class="container"></container>
</footer>
```

How I select the second .container using css?
That is correct?

```
.container:not(header .container):not(footer .container) {
}
```

Would be a best practice add?

```
 <main>
 <div class="container"></div>
 </main>
```

Thank you.

Comment: just add a custom class to your 2nd container div. Should be very easy instead of complicating it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the nth element, you can use the following code:

```css
 .container:nth-child(2) {
            background: red;
  }
```

```html
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="container">1</container>
        </header>
        
        <div class="container">2</div>
        
        <footer>
        <div class="container">3</container>
        </footer>
   
</body>
```